# Problem with LIKE command on Visual Studio 2010 and Access, VB.NET

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I have searched for answers but the ones I have found I can't get working.

I have a database written in MS Access located on a network drive. The front-end has been written in Visual Studio 2010 (VB). I can get the data OK but I need to do a LIKE search to see if there is any records that might match what the user has entered.

Essentially the database is a list of barcodes provided on media. Users provide a list of barcodes but this is done by eye and the last two letters / numbers can be missed, due to size, location or not provided. When scanning the barcode it reads the full details. For example 'AIF00511L6'.

If there is a duplicate then I need to inform the user that there might be one or more records. Duplicate barcodes are possible (don't ask), so I need to provide the details to the user so that they can make the final decision as to if this is the same or different media.

The code I have in VB is:

```
Dim SQLString as String = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS Count1 " &
                          "FROM " & Table & " " & 
                          "WHERE " & Column & " " & 
                          "LIKE '*" & Search & "*';"
```

The code at runtime SQLString is:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Count1 FROM Assets WHERE aItem LIKE '*IF00511L*';
```

This works OK in Access (returns 1) but it's not working from VS. I have tried using the '%' in place of '*' but this is not working either. In VS it returns 0.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I saved and restarted my project and made the below change and now it's working!

```
Dim SQLString As String = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS Count1 " &
                          "FROM " & Table & " " &
                          "WHERE " & Column & " " &
                          "LIKE '%" & Search & "%';"
```

So it needed to be a % and not *, something I tried and didn't work, Oh well.